# How to design VR app with realtime mobile camera to detect things?

Tags: android, tensorflow, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

I want to design VR app in android which detects/recognise things using camera. and show details.
I know about unity, but this shows assets provided while designing background like gaming set.

In augmented reality we can scan image and accordingly we get results, the same way I want using VR screen.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Vuforia](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Getting-Started-with-Vuforia-for-Android-Development.html) library for android. It works like a charm.
I have implemented what you're talking about. It'll take a little effort and time to get the hang of it. But it'll definitely work.

Comment: Mohsen could you guide me, how to approach for this?